# getting sum of list in list of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider this mongo document, an order with an internal list of products with their counts:

```
{
  ordernumber: "1234"
  detail: [
    { "number": "987",
    "count": 10 },
    { "number": "654",
    "count": 5 }
  ]
}
```

How do we get the sum of all counts with mongodb shell? I always get zero for sum and dont know what to pass for _id.

```
db.preorders.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $group: { _id: "$_id", total: { $sum: "$detail.count" } } }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `$unwind` first, then `$group` on `null`.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TwGWVVyYGWp) for your reference.